# Falha ao atualizar campo de todos os registros com o path dos arquivos utilizando JDBC

Tags: java, jdbc, oracle11g

Estou fazendo a migração de arquivos pdf armazenados no banco para sistemas de arquivos. No código como poderá ser visto abaixo, utilizo um algoritmo que gera o nome dos arquivos e os salvam em um diretório gerado através da data de inclusão do documento.

Até aí tudo bem, pois os arquivos estão sendo salvos corretamente. Mas preciso também, armazenar o path destes arquivos na coluna path do database. O problema que está ocorrendo é que só estou conseguindo atualizar apenas o primeiro registro e de forma errada, pois ele salva com o path do último arquivo gerado.

Considerando que todos os registros estão com o campo path vazios, como posso atualizar todos os registros, associando o path correto para todos os arquivos?

```
public class MigracaoDados {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        ResultSet rs = null;

        try {
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver").newInstance();
            Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.1.102:1521:xe","teste","123456");
            System.out.println("Conectado!");
            Statement statement = connection.createStatement();

            String sql = "SELECT id, dthinclusao, path, documentoarquivo FROM processodocumento";
            rs = statement.executeQuery(sql);

            while (rs.next()) {    

                //obtendo o arquivo no banco
                int id = rs.findColumn("id");
                Blob blob = rs.getBlob("documentoarquivo");

                //stream para leitura
                InputStream is = blob.getBinaryStream();

                String data = rs.getString("dthinclusao");
                String s_ano = data.substring(0,4);
                String s_mes = data.substring(5,7);
                String s_dia = data.substring(8,10);
                System.out.println(s_dia + "/" + s_mes + "/" + s_ano);
                System.out.println("---------------");

                //criacao do diretorio
                File novoDiretorio = new File("/home/phoenix/Documentos/workspace/files/" + "/"
                        + s_ano + "/"
                        + s_mes + "/"
                        + s_dia + "/");
                novoDiretorio.mkdirs();

                //geracao aleatoria dos nomes dos arquivos
                String descricaoArquivo = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

                //criacao do arquivo
                File file = new File(novoDiretorio, descricaoArquivo + ".pdf");
                System.out.println("Path: " + file);

                //atualizar campo path de acordo o nome do arquivo gerado
                String sqlUpdt = "UPDATE processodocumento SET path=? WHERE id = ?";            
                PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(sqlUpdt);
                String path = file.toString();

                stmt.setString(1, path);
                stmt.setInt(2, id);
                stmt.executeUpdate();

                //stream para escrita
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);    

                int b = 0;
                while ((b = is.read()) != -1)
                {
                    //efetuar a escrita no sistema de arquivos
                    fos.write(b);
                }
                fos.close();
                stmt.close();
            }
            statement.close();
            System.out.println("Todos os arquivos foram gravados no sistema de arquivos!");
            System.out.println("Desconectado!");

        } catch (SQLException e)
        {
            e.getMessage (); e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolvido, apenas substituí essa linha

```
int id = rs.findColumn("id");
```

por essa outra

```
int id = rs.getInt("id");
```